# Knockout set Dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I  have a language dropdown in layout.chtml using knockout js

```
 <select id="Language" class="styled-select" data-bind="value: Language,options: locale, value: selectedLocale, optionsText: 'name'"></select>


 var viewModel = this;

 viewModel.locale = [{ id: 1, name: 'English' }, { id: 2, name: 'Spanish' }];

 viewModel.selectedLocale = ko.observable(sessionStorage.culture);
 viewModel.selectedLocaleValue = ko.computed(function () {
     sessionStorage.culture = viewModel.selectedLocale() && viewModel.selectedLocale().id;
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

While run the application I have change the dropdown and choose the spanish then When i click the submit button the page got re-rendered and again re sets the culture session value with the default English.

The following are the possible ways to fix the issue.

1. While re-rendering do some tweaking and set the dropdown selected value and should reflect in the culture session
2. Avoid re-rendering while post action from Login
3. Have Ajax call for post.

I have tried option 1 But I dont know how to set the selected value in dropdown

Comment: I would suggest you to go with 3rd option as it would increase the user experience of your page and also why would you want to render the whole page just to refresh one component on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing only the `id` of the selected locale in the session, however you need to store whole locale object in the `selectedLocale` to make the drop-down pre-selection work.

So you need to lookup the stored locale by `id`:

```
var localeFromSession = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.locale, function(item) {
    return item.id == sessionStorage.culture;
});
```

And set it to the `selectedLocale`:

```
viewModel.selectedLocale = ko.observable(localeFromSession);
```

As an alternative solution you can also set the `optionsValue: 'id'` in your binding. In this case `viewModel.selectedLocale` will only contain the `id` and not the whole object. However in this case you need to change the saving code too, and also other places where you expect to have the complete locale object selected.